# get max time duration for max work done for single entity

Tags: java, algorithm

here is my data, trying to solve below puzzle

```
#ID      Date            GroupId      Code        Days        Lift     wt
#100     03-01-2020      LM100        500          30           5      kg
#100     03-15-2020      LM100        500          30           3      kg
#100     04-10-2020      LM100        500          20           20     kg
#100     05-15-2020      LM100        500          30           5      kg
```

want to calculate the longest duration with highest lift for every ID in data.

Lets say in first record, it says, ID 100 started on 1st march to lift 5kg everyday for next 30 days. But on 15th march ID100 started to lift 3kg too for next 30 days. So from 15th march to 30th march ID 100 is lifting 8 kg every day. SO that's how data is connected.

I'm not able to think of any logic to write for this.

Can anyone suggest any idea or logic for this ?

```
Update:
```

More definition on Data

Person started lifting 5kg/day from 1st march for next 30days (meaning until 30th march). But he started one more routine to lift 3kg/day too from 15th march for next 30 days (meaning until 14th April). So 1st and 2nd routine are being overlapped from 15th march to 30th March, that's why he's lifting 5+3 = 8 kg / day. That's how the data is for a person

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "longest duration with highest lift".  If you can find the words to express this more clearly, you may find yourself working out the logic at the same time.

Comment: Maybe first choose max_Lift and then max_Duration for that Lift. 20kg_MaxLift for 20  Days.(only 1 choice, but  MaxLift can have multiple choices->Duration and select max) If it is this then it's pretty simple to be implement.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, from which duration (start to end) person is lifting max weight ?

Comment: Why do you say “15th march to 30th march” when the last row for the 15th says 30 days? That would mean middle of April.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I'm just trying to give example. Person started lifting 5kg/day from 1st march for next 30days (meaning until 30th march). But he started one more routine to lift 3kg/day too from 15th march for next 30 days (meaning until 14th April). So 1st and 2nd routine are being overlapped from 15th march to 30th March, that's why he's lifting 5+3 = 8 kg / day. That's how the data is for a person

Comment: As first post, first need to compute MaxLift and then select Max Days. (counting overlapping as you clarify). Say somehow with overlap for 10 session in 1 day the MaxLift is 100Kg then this is the answer, doesn't matter if in other day the agregate lift was 90, 80, etc.

Comment: Tip: Instead of more examples, focus on *definitions* and *business rules*.

Comment: When writing a question with some data it's better also to specify the desired solution based on the data provided. In this case what response you need it ? (eg: response is 123 lift for 321 days) .As others mentioned it can be very vague without. Take a pencil and paper, it may help.

Comment: Is the range of days finite? Such that you could easily represent every single possible day in an array? (If not, then there are interval trees to efficiently solve this problem.)

Comment: @Neil, eventually 'range of days' is finite, based on humans life-span. In OP scenarios maybe it's better to have his clarification.

Comment: This is a similar problem to finding the closest surface in a 1D scene graph, for which an interval tree or segment tree might be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

As this appears to be a schoolwork assignment I’ll be a little vague to let you work out the details.

Define [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) class to represent your inputs. Add an extra member field beyond what you mentioned in Question: the possible end date. Calculate this by making a `LocalDate` objectof the start date, then call `plusDays` passing your `days` count to get the end date.

```
record LiftSpan ( int participantId, LocalDate start, int days, LocalDate end, int groupId, int code, int lift, String unitOfWeight ) {}
```

Determine the first and last date of the overall date range. You neglected to define precisely the last date in your Question, so I’ll have to leave that to you to determine.

Start with the first date. Loop for each day in the overall range. For each day in that range, search the list of `LiftSpan` objects where the range contains that nth date. If there is only one object covering that date, continue looping. When you find more than one match, make a record from that first date to this date. Calculate elapsed days with `ChronoUnit.DAYS`.  Copy over the appropriate fields for weight and code. Then replace your tracking of that first date with this date. Continue onwards, day by day, accumulating more `LiftSpan` objects. Stop looping when moving past the overall date range.

Optimizations are possible. If you sort the original set of objects, then you could compare their dates without going day by day. This alternative approach also eliminates needing to search the entire list repeatedly. But for a beginner programmer, the approach described first above would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could start in the following way.

Mainly you need to compute and store aggregate result somewhere, here used a `key-value` data structure. After aggregation, grab the result based on your criteria.

In this case, it is just a simple scenarios based on one person which do some lift schemas (2 schemas for some days). The result should be the day in which the lift is maximum. Latter just adjust based on your requirements.(with max. days for each persons, etc)

```
public class TestLift
{
    static List<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //default sort by data
    static Map<Date, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        run();
    }
    public static void run()
    {
        list.add(new Record(new GregorianCalendar(2022,0,10).getTime(),3,10));
        list.add(new Record(new GregorianCalendar(2022,0,12).getTime(),3,20));
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            //till no. of days 
            for(int j=0;j<list.get(i).days;j++)
            {
                Date d=list.get(i).date;
                Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
                c.setTime(d);
                //add extra days
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, j);
                d=c.getTime();
                //System.out.println(i+":"+j+"="+d);
                if(map.get(d)==null)
                {
                    map.put(d, list.get(i).lift);
                }
                else
                {
                    //add extra
                    map.put(d,map.get(d)+list.get(i).lift);
                }
            }
            //look over aggregate map and find max lift
            for(Date d:map.keySet())
            {
                System.out.println(map.get(d)+" kg at :"+d);
            }
            System.out.println("###after add new record###");
            
        }
        
        Date result = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
        System.out.println("\nresult="+map.get(result)+ " kg at :"+ result );
    }

    static class Record
    {
        public Date date;
        public int days;
        public double lift;
        public Record(Date date, int days, double lift)
        {
            this.date=date;
            this.days = days;
            this.lift = lift;
        }
    }   
}
```

Output

```
//computing aggregate step by step
10.0 kg at :Mon Jan 10 00:00:00 EET 2022
10.0 kg at :Tue Jan 11 00:00:00 EET 2022
10.0 kg at :Wed Jan 12 00:00:00 EET 2022
###after add new record###
10.0 kg at :Mon Jan 10 00:00:00 EET 2022
10.0 kg at :Tue Jan 11 00:00:00 EET 2022
30.0 kg at :Wed Jan 12 00:00:00 EET 2022
20.0 kg at :Thu Jan 13 00:00:00 EET 2022
20.0 kg at :Fri Jan 14 00:00:00 EET 2022
###after add new record###

result=30.0 kg at :Wed Jan 12 00:00:00 EET 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the maximum weight date range *per* `ID`, every `ID` in the data is independent. However, in general, for one `ID`, one could have complex multiple overlapping segments with arbitrary length, (a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).)

One solution would use a map from the `ID` to a minimum heap on `LocalDate` in which one pre-calculates the `Integer` change in weight for the two ends, `Map<Integer, <LocalDate, Integer>PriorityQueue>`. Each record adds two `<LocalDate, Integer>` to the heap, one positive weight, and the later one the opposite.

When one has read all the records, for each `ID`, we can remap to calculate the date range for the maximum lift. If two date ranges are the same weight, the later one is chosen (slightly simpler.) We keep track of the current maximum weight, the date range of the current maximum, and current weight; say, for every unique `ID`, have `max`, `start`, `end`, `current`. While not empty, popping the heap results in `date`, `weight`:

- If `weight > 0`: if `weight + current >= max` is exceeded, then `start = date`, `max = current + weight`.
- If `weight < 0`: if `weight == max` then `end = date`.
- `current += weight`

This will resolve, I think, in `O(n log n)`.